# Is there a village in the mountains of central Asia that isn't very hot in August from where daytrips can be made without long drives?

Tags: kyrgyzstan, central-asia, tajikistan

My wife, myself and our baby want to go somewhere in the mountains of central Asia (Kyrgyzstan, Tajikistan or similar) in August. We're looking for a village or two where we can settle for a couple of weeks and do day trips. The idea is to be somewhere that's not too hot and that doesn't require long drives since I don't think the baby will take too kindly to it.

Does anyone know any villages that meet these criteria?

Comment: Hi and welcome. [We don't really do recommendations here on Travel.SE.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help) Please take the site [tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [help centre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help) to gain a better understanding on how this site works.

Comment: Just go in September instead and stay in the city center. Villages in Central Asia are extremely under developed, to the point where you'd be lucky to get running water and electricity.